# finding irqs of gVNIC rx queues

Tags: linux-networking, google-compute-engine

I run `n2d-standard-16` server on GCE with ubuntu 21.10 and gVnic driver enabled. I have a hard time understanding what interrupts are responsible for rx queues and how many Rx queues it has.

On the one hand:

```
>ls /sys/class/net/ens4/device/msi_irqs/
30  31  32  33  34  35  36  37  38  39  40  41  42  43  44  45  46
```

so it's 16.

On another hand:

```
ls /sys/class/net/ens4/queues/
rx-0  rx-1  rx-2  rx-3  rx-4  rx-5  rx-6  rx-7  tx-0  tx-1  tx-2  tx-3  tx-4  tx-5  tx-6  tx-7
```

it shows 8 rx queues and 8 tx queues.
And finally, just to add to the confusion, `/proc/interrupts/ shows the following:

```
... eth%d-ntfy-block.0 ...
....|||||||||||||||||||...
... eth%d-ntfy-block.15...
```

and `ethtool -l ens4` shows 8 rx-queues and 8 tx-queues:

```
Channel parameters for ens4:
Pre-set maximums:
RX:     8
TX:     8
Current hardware settings:
RX:     8
TX:     8
```

is there a reliable mapping that shows the name of the interrupt per Tx/Rx queue?

Answer (score 0):

===Second response===

Using commands in the Linux terminal, you are not gonna be able to see the interruptions by name. As your Ubuntu Server is running in Google Compute Engine, you can use the monitoring tools that GCP has available for your project:

1.- [Cloud Trace](https://cloud.google.com/trace)
2.- [Google Cloud Firewall Rules Logging](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/identity-security/google-cloud-firewall-rules-logging-how-and-why-you-should-use-it)
3.- [VPC Flow Logs](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/using-flow-logs)
4.- [HTTP(S) Load Balancing logging and monitoring](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/https/https-logging-monitoring)

In some of them maybe you are going to need to make some changes to your VM’s current setting, for example, enable logs for an HTTP(S) Load Balancing. So, those are the tools that can give you more specific information about your project’s network and it’s behavior.